# Uniform distribution parameter estimation

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

How do I estimate the parameter, when the distribution is $\mathrm{U}(-a,a)$?
I get $a=\min(X_i)$, $b=\max(X_i)$, when it's $\mathrm{U}(a,b)$, but these do not work here.

Comment: Here's a hint:  use your intuition.  If your sample is $\{-5, 3, 1, -4, 2, 4\}$, what is the **smallest** possible value of $a$ you could have for such a sample?  Naturally, $a \ge 5$.  If $a < 5$, then you could not have observed $-5$.

Comment: @heropup 
So, the a^ can be max|x_i |?